# Is there a way to rename SQL result Grid tabs in LINQPad?

Tags: sql, linqpad

In LINQPad, I'm using a single query window to execute several complex, but related SQL statements. That works great since LINQPad creates an output grid tab for each statement result. However, I'd love to be able to specify a name for those tabs, so it's easier to remember which result is which, e.g., "Companies" and "Users" rather than "Grid 1" and "Grid 2".

[image: LINQPad default output grid naming]

I was hoping to find a way of decorating each statement and having that translate to the name of the grid tab. Something to the effect of:

```
["Companies"]
SELECT * FROM Companies

["Users"]
SELECT * FROM Users
```

(Doing the above just tries to execute an SPROC)

Is there a built-in way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I do this is to change the Language to C# Statements and then use `this.ExecuteQueryDynamic` to perform the Sql statement.

eg

```
this.ExecuteQueryDynamic("select * from Companies").ToArray().Dump("Companies", true);  
this.ExecuteQueryDynamic("select * from Users    ").ToArray().Dump("Users"    , true);
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you! I'd played around with different versions of `ExecuteQueryDynamic` and `ExecuteQuery<dynamic>` but I'd either run into the situation where only one dynamic query could be run at a time (subsequent statements ignored) or I'd just get a list of System.Object back.